PermissionError: Access is denied undetected_chromedriver when using user_multi_procs = True
I get this error when is use the option user_multi_procs in undetected_chromedriver.
The full error message
Exception in thread Thread-1 (check_link):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\programeren jef\pandabuyprogram\test.py", line 73, in check_link
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, user_multi_procs = True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.patcher.auto()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 138, in auto
    list(map(lambda f: f.unlink(), files))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 138, in <lambda>
    list(map(lambda f: f.unlink(), files))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1147, in unlink
    os.unlink(self)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\appdata\\roaming\\undetected_chromedriver\\undetected\\chromedriver-win32'

Code
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, user_multi_procs = True)
login(driver)
driver.get(link)

I've tried to not use user_multi_procs but i am using threading so than it gives me an other error massage.
Exception in thread Thread-2 (check_link):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\programeren jef\pandabuyprogram\test.py", line 73, in check_link
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.patcher.auto()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 178, in auto
    self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 310, in unzip_package
    os.rename(os.path.join(self.zip_path, exe_path), self.executable_path)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\user\\appdata\\roaming\\undetected_chromedriver\\undetected\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver.exe' -> 'C:\\Users\\user\\appdata\\roaming\\undetected_chromedriver\\undetected_chromedriver.exe'

I need to use threading for what i am doing so my code is faster. Does anyone know a solution for this?

did you try to run as administrator
